# Question on strictly positive measure of a level set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f \in W^{2,p}(U)$ for $1 \le p \lt \infty$ where $U$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and $g \in L^{\infty}(U)$ with $g(f)=f$ almost everywhere on $U$. I have trouble understanding why the following holds:

> Assume that the set $\{f=0\}$ is non empty and moreover that $g \lt 1$ in $\{f=0\}$. Then it has a strictly
>   positive lebesgue measure.

I know that $\{f=0\}$ is a (relatively) closed set but that is not enough for the strict inequality. What do I miss? Is it because it contains an open set?

Any help/hints are much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you not have any additional assumptions? Unless I'm missing something, $f(x) = x_1^2+x_2^2$ is an easy counterexample.

Comment: @ktoi I just edited my question...

Comment: What is the connection between $f$ and $g$. The example given by ktoi is still valid with $g=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm sorry I didn't mention it from the beginning. I edited

Comment: @kaithkolesidou What do you mean by $g(f)$? If it's functional composition, then the assumption $g<1$ on $\{f = 0\}$ doesn't really tell you anything and taking $g(x) = x$ my example still remains valid. Also it seems like you need more regularity assumptions on $g$; if $\{ f = 0 \}$ is a null set then the condition $g < 1$ on $\{f = 0\}$ gives hardly any restriction on $g.$